# Spring batch test for dynamically created job

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-batch

In my application I have multiple jobs So i created Dynamic jobs.I have no issue in running this application. I want to do unit testing for the dynamically created job.

I want to set my job to JobLauncherTestUtils .

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest()
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class SpringBatchIntegrationTest {
    @Inject
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    @Inject
    private JobLauncher mJobLauncher;
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
    @Inject
    BatchJobConfig mBatchJobConfig;
    public void initailizeJobLauncherTestUtils() {
        jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(mBatchJobConfig.createJob());
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(mJobLauncher);
    }
```

This is how im initializing JobLauncherTestUtils . When I run this I get below error
Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJob' parameter 0; Can anyone tell me how do I do spring batch test for dynamic jobs.
I don't have much knowledge about Junit. I just started to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@SpringBatchTest` already adds a bean of type `JobLauncherTestUtils` in your test context (See [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/test/context/SpringBatchTest.html)), so you don't need to add it yourself.

However, `JobLauncherTestUtils` requires a job bean, and it looks like you don't have one defined in your test context. What you can do is define one in a configuration class and import it in your test context, something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ContextConfiguration
public class SpringBatchIntegrationTest {
   @Inject
   private JobRepository jobRepository;
   @Inject
   private JobLauncher mJobLauncher;
   @Inject
   private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

   // No need for initailizeJobLauncherTestUtils

   // Add your test method

   @Configuration
   @Import(BatchJobConfig.class) // you might need this or not depending on what's defined in BatchJobConfig
   static class MyJobConfiguration {

      @Bean
      public Job job(BatchJobConfig mBatchJobConfig) {
         return mBatchJobConfig.createJob();
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for Replying . I did as you said . Now I found another issue  Error creating bean with name 'jobRepositoryTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0;

Comment: Yes, `jobRepositoryTestUtils` is another utility added by `@SpringBatchTest` (see javadoc) which requires a datasource to be present in the test context.